# Hibernate: queda de desempenho de query após algumas repetições

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de Gestão de Fazendas. Uma das consultas básicas é listar os animais por tipo que estão vivos (`inFarm = true`). Segue abaixo o método que executa esta consulta.

```
public List<T> findByInFarm(T model, boolean inFarm) throws DAOException {

    List<T> animalList = null;
    EntityManager em = JpaHelper.getEntityManager();
    Query query = em
            .createQuery("SELECT a FROM " + model.getClass().getSimpleName() + " a WHERE a.inFarm = :inFarm");
    query.setParameter("inFarm", inFarm);
    try {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        animalList = (List<T>) query.getResultList();
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("findByInFarm() demorou " + (end - start) + " millis");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new DAOException(e.getCause().toString());
    } finally {
        if (em.isOpen()) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
    return animalList;
}
```

A consulta retorna o resultado esperado, porém após executar a mesma query algumas vezes, o desempenho cai muito. Eu inseri um `System.currentTimeMillis()` antes de `query.getResultList()` e um depois para medir o desempenho da consulta e rodei o teste abaixo.

```
public void test() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            List<Cow> cowList = new Cow().findByInFarm(true);
            new Thread().sleep(2000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Segue abaixo o resultado obtido após algumas repetições:

- findByInFarm() demorou 1017 millis
- findByInFarm() demorou 615 millis
- findByInFarm() demorou 606 millis
- findByInFarm() demorou 591 millis
- findByInFarm() demorou 566 millis
- findByInFarm() demorou 561 millis
- findByInFarm() demorou 586 millis
- findByInFarm() demorou 588 millis
- findByInFarm() demorou 546 millis
- findByInFarm() demorou 3036 millis
- findByInFarm() demorou 4876 millis
- findByInFarm() demorou 4959 millis
- findByInFarm() demorou 4904 millis
- findByInFarm() demorou 4924 millis
- findByInFarm() demorou 4936 millis

As primeiras consultas são bem rápidas porém após a décima repetição o tempo aumenta muito. Alguém poderia dar uma dica onde podem estar as possíveis causas disso?

Obs: Estou usando Hibernate 5.2, Postgresql 9.4 e Java 8.

Comment: Para tentar melhorar um pouco, tente criar um [índice nessa coluna](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createindex.html). Mas isso ainda não responde sua pergunta.

Comment: [Resposta nesse link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908764/executing-same-query-makes-time-difference-in-postgresql), mas necessita de tradução. :(

Comment: @Everson, a tabela já tem índice. Acredito que o problema não está no PostgreSQL pois quando executo o mesmo SELECT direto no banco (usando pgAdmin), este problema não ocorre.

Comment: Quase 5 segundos para executar uma consulta tão simples é bem estranho mesmo. Até porque, o Hibernate usa cache de 1° nível, assim, depois da primeira consulta, ele já buscaria nesse cache o resultado. Tenta alterar a versão do driver jdbc, veja se muda alguma coisa.

Comment: Resolvi meu problema, faltava um pool de conexões. Segui o tutorial deste [site](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-configure-the-c3p0-connection-pool-in-hibernate/) e deu certo. Obrigado a todos.